# Questions about Xposed API int method

Tags: java, xposed

Public String class => Hooking success

Public int class => Hooking failure

```
Button btn;
TextView up;
int count = 0;

public int ButtonClickCount(int a)
{
    return a++;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("test");
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.up);

    btn.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            up.setText("" + ButtonClickCount(++count));
        }
    }));
}
```

}

public class Hook implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

```
@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(final XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    /*final ApplicationInfo appinfo = lpparam.appInfo;
    XposedBridge.log(String.valueOf(appinfo));*/

    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.study")) {
        //XposedBridge.log("PackageName Error");
        return;
    } else {
        XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
    }


    findAndHookMethod(
            "com.study.MainActivity",
            lpparam.classLoader,
            "ButtonClickCount",

            new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                    XposedBridge.log("before");
                }

                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    super.afterHookedMethod(param);
                    XposedBridge.log("after");
                    param.setResult(100);
                }
            }

    );
}

/*private void findAndHookMethod(String s, ClassLoader classLoader, Class<int[]> integerClass, String randomRange, XC_MethodHook xc_methodHook) {
}*/
```

}

Why is the int class not hooked? i need help

```
findAndHookMethod(
        "com.study.MainActivity",
        lpparam.classLoader,
        "ButtonClickCount",
```

this code is error.. (NoSuchMethodError)

If executed with the following code, the hooking module does not work.

```
findAndHookMethod(
        "com.study.MainActivity",
        lpparam.classLoader,
        "ButtonClickCount",
        int.class,
```

Comment: Use a decompiler like apktool or Jadx to check if in the created APK the method `ButtonClickCount(int)` exists or if the compiler has just inlined the code as the method is an instance method but does not make use of it (hence it can be implemented as static and as it is only used once it can just be inlined to improve performance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After checking it in jadx, the method name was the same.
After changing only the method to hook in the same hooking module, hooking the method that returns the String value succeeds. However, as in the code above, the method that returns an int value cannot be hooked.