# The findAndHookMethod code in java Xposed is wrong. Help!! (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, xposed

Hooking target : ButtonClickCount(int a)

If the code below

```
public int ButtonClickCount()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Success with the hooking code below.

```
    findAndHookMethod(
            "com.study.MainActivity",
            lpparam.classLoader,
            "ButtonClickCount",

            new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                    XposedBridge.log("before");
                }

                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    super.afterHookedMethod(param);
                    XposedBridge.log("after");
                    param.setResult(10000);
                }
            }

    );
}
```

But, If the ButtonClickCount method receives an argument value, NoSuchMethodError is raised.

```
public int ButtonClickCount(int a)
{
    return a++;
}
```

It's an Error in findAndHookMethod and I don't know what to add to the code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where the difference is between this question and your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62043849/150978)?

Comment: I have tried countless attempts in about two weeks to resolve this error. So I don't remember exactly where the difference was. 
For sure, when adding int.class in the last question, NoSuchMethodError did not occur, but my hooking module could not be loaded. Probably after the last question, I changed the provided '/lib/~~~.jar' in the build.gradle file to provided 'de.robv.android.xposed: api: 82' so I can use int.class normally in findAndHookMethod It seems to have been.

Comment: Come now, I don't think there is a big difference between that question and this one.

Comment: If there is no big difference why have you created another question?

Comment: If there is a difference, the last question asks how to set in findAndHookMethod when getting the argument value from the method to be hooked, and this question is the question about why NoSuchMethodError occurs for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

i solved.

example code 1

```
public int ButtonClickCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

.

```
    findAndHookMethod(
            "com.study.MainActivity",
            lpparam.classLoader,
            "ButtonClickCount",
            new XC_MethodHook()
```

.

example code 2

```
public int ButtonClickCount(int a) {
    return a++;
}
```

.

```
    findAndHookMethod(
            "com.study.MainActivity",
            lpparam.classLoader,
            "ButtonClickCount",
            int.class,
            new XC_MethodHook()
```

example code 3

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
    this.btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    this.up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.up);
    this.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

.

```
    findAndHookMethod(
            "com.study.MainActivity",
            lpparam.classLoader,
            "ButtonClickCount",
            Bundle.class,
            new XC_MethodHook()
```

As you can see from the example code above, if you are hooking a method that does not take an argument value, you can simply put class name, classloader, methodname, object.

However, if you receive an int argument value a called int a from the method to hook as in example code 2, you must add int.class in findAndHookMethod. If you don't add it, you'll see NoSuchMethodError in the Xposed application.

If you try to hook the onCreate method as in example code 3, the onCreate method takes an argument of type Bundle. So, you need to add Bundle.class in findAndHookMethod.

This DOC helped me with the resolution.
https://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.html#findAndHookMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

If this doesn't work, check your Android Studio version. In my case, I ran downgrade from version 3.6.2 to version 2.3.2 and then ran it.

I hope my solution helps someone.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not an answer, but just dumped code. Please explain why this solves your problem.

Comment: I am not sure of the policy for the stackoverflow site. You seem to have a complaint about why you repeated similar questions. Sorry about that. And could you explain why this is not a solution ?? I don't know Xposed yet.

Comment: Because it is just code. Just code helps nobody without the explanation why it works (in this case why you add Bundle.class), especially when comparing it to the code posted in your first question.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. I started modifying the code by referring to the Xposed API documentation and I know why. However, it was difficult to express it in English. Thank you for your response. Let me add a description of the solution.